# c++ Is it possible to pass an object type into a function to be compared against

Tags: c++, polymorphism, typeid, typeinfo

I have a situation where I need to find out if a derived object is stored in a vector within another object, and want to functionize this.  I can't figure out a way to do exactly what I want, or determine whether it is possible.  I have a solution that works which I'm including, but it would be cleaner if there is a direct method to achieve the goal.

This is essentially what I want to do:

```
class IFruit
{
public:
    virtual ~IFruit(){};
};
class Apple : public IFruit {};
class Banana : public IFruit {};
class Orange : public IFruit {};

class FruitBowl
{
public:
    bool HasFruit( datatype?? FruitType )
    {
        for ( auto iter : m_Fruit )
        {
            if ( typeof( iter ) == typeof( FruitType ) )
            {
                return ( true );
            }
        }
        return ( false );
    }

    vector< IFruit* > m_Fruit;
};

int main()
{
    FruitBowl Snacks;
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Banana );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Apple );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Orange );

    if ( Snacks.HasFruit( Orange ) )
    {
        cout << "There is an orange available";
    }

    return ( 0 );
}
```

This is a workaround that achieves the goal, but it has the extra step of providing the callback which I'd love to eradicate:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class IFruit
{
public:
    virtual ~IFruit(){};
};
class Apple : public IFruit {};
class Banana : public IFruit {};
class Orange : public IFruit {};

class FruitBowl
{
public:
    bool HasFruit( function< bool( IFruit* ) > fnCompareFruitType )
    {
        for ( auto iter : m_Fruit )
        {
            if ( fnCompareFruitType( iter ) )
            {
                return ( true );
            }
        }
        return ( false );
    }

    vector< IFruit* > m_Fruit;
};

int main()
{
    FruitBowl Snacks;
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Banana );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Apple );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Orange );

    if ( Snacks.HasFruit( []( IFruit* TestFruit ){ return ( dynamic_cast< Orange* >( TestFruit ) != nullptr ); } ) )
    {
        cout << "There is an orange available";
    }

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: How about templatizing the HasFruit() function?  I'm not a c++ expert, so I haven't worked it out exactly yet, but something like `template <typename T> bool HasFruit( T * ) const { ... }`

Comment: @DaveM. I had the same though, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass a type as a runtime function parameter, but you can use one as a compile time template parameter of a function template:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class IFruit
{
public:
    virtual ~IFruit(){};
};
class Apple : public IFruit {};
class Banana : public IFruit {};
class Orange : public IFruit {};

class FruitBowl
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool HasFruit()
    {
        return std::any_of(m_Fruit.begin(), m_Fruit.end(),
                          [](IFruit* fruit) {
                              return dynamic_cast<T*>(fruit) != nullptr;
                          });
    }

    std::vector< IFruit* > m_Fruit;
};


int main()
{
    FruitBowl Snacks;
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Banana );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Apple );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Orange );

    if ( Snacks.HasFruit<Orange>() )
    {
        std::cout << "There is an orange available";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, +1 for the simplicity of the logic

Comment: @MilesBudnek - Thanks for clarification on passing the type. I didn't think it could be done, couldn't find a way to do it, and definitely couldn't uncover anything that directly stated that it wasn't possible.  Hard to find information about things that have no reason to have an answer.

Comment: `HasFruit` can even be `const`.

Comment: Best solution! Thanks Miles. If ever C++ has a neater syntax for dynamic casting, but again!! Its the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

To me, solution would be to make an enum for all the "Fruit types" and use it as your parameter's datatype. You can make a comparison then

Comment: I need the caller to be completely divorced from knowing about fruit types it does not need to know about. It's primarily about making the working version of the code cleaner if the language has features to achieve the end goal

Comment: Oh right!! Well I am thinking about it/awaiting a better answer. Right now, _as far as my limited knowledge is concerned, I am not finding a better solution than enum_. I am sure there will be many hopefully!!

Comment: Although using enums would be possible, it would pollute the code significantly and create unnecessary maintenance, given that the types are already defined by polymorphism. My current solution only has the one extra step of providing the lambda, whereas adding an enum list and setting it in all of the derived classes would just add unnecessary baggage.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class IFruit {
  public:
    virtual     ~IFruit( void ) { }
} ;

class Apple : public IFruit { };
class Banana : public IFruit { };
class Orange : public IFruit { };

class FruitBowl : public vector<IFruit *> {
  public:
    template <typename T> bool HasFruit( void ) const {
        for (auto i : vector<IFruit *>( *this )) {
            if (typeid(*i) == typeid(T)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} ;

int
main( int, char ** )
{
    FruitBowl b;

    b.push_back( new Apple );
    b.push_back( new Banana );
//    b.push_back( new Orange );

    if (b.HasFruit<Orange>( ))    // thanks M.M.!
        cout << "found one" << endl;
    else
        cout << "no oranges" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe there's a sexier way to do the call?  `(Orange *)0` is kinda ugly.

Comment: Get rid of the parameter, and call function as `b.HasFruit<Orange>()`

Comment: I like this.  This is the paradigm I started down the path of, but couldn't think of a way to get the type through to the HasFruit function.  Although it's still not quite as nice as I'd ultimately like, it is definitely a large step closer

Comment: `(Orange *)0` has more swag Dave :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

class IFruit
{
public:
    virtual ~IFruit(){};
};
class Apple : public IFruit {};
class Banana : public IFruit {};
class Orange : public IFruit {};

class FruitBowl
{
public:
    //uses tempalte to accept any type
    template<typename FruitType>
    bool HasFruit( FruitType fruit )
    {
        for ( auto iter : m_Fruit )
        {
            if ( typeid(* iter ).hash_code() == typeid( fruit ).hash_code() )
            {
                return ( true );
            }
        }
        return ( false );
    }

    std::vector<IFruit*> m_Fruit;
};

int main()
{
    FruitBowl Snacks;
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Banana );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Apple );
    Snacks.m_Fruit.push_back( new Orange );

    if ( Snacks.HasFruit( Orange() ) )
    {
        cout << "There is an orange available";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No fruit available";   
    }

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Live Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37a3e1b4f5567775

Comment: You can use `==` directly on typeinfo, don't need to make hash code.

Comment: I prefer the suggestion from Dave.M because it doesn't require instantiation of an Orange

Comment: I thought so as well, but a quick look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid showed `assert(&ti1 == &ti2); // not guaranteed` but `assert(ti1.hash_code() == ti2.hash_code()); // guaranteed`

Comment: @jgibbs I tend to agree, I only put a few minutes of thought into my answer.

Comment: @AlexZywicki Interesting about typeid and hash_code...but you can see how that could happen with shared libraries & such.

Comment: Also note that `std::type_info::hash_code()` can return the same value for different types.  The only guarantee is that it will return the same value for the same type.

Comment: I have a feeling that dynamic_cast<T> is probably the best solution